# Cassandra help : Supporting fast queries using either part of composite key

Tags: cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra and was unclear on the best way to store my data to support my query needs.  I want to be able to search my data based on either of the keys, or both.  To illustrate I will use this table example:

```
CREATE TABLE temperature (
weatherstation_id text,
event_time timestamp,
temperature text,
PRIMARY KEY (weatherstation_id,event_time)
);
```

This works great for queries like these two:

```
SELECT event_time,temperature FROM temperature WHERE weatherstation_id=’1234ABCD’;
```

...because it goes directly to a single partition

```
SELECT temperature FROM temperature WHERE weatherstation_id=’1234ABCD’ AND event_time > ’2013-04-03 07:01:00′ AND event_time < ’2013-04-03 07:04:00′;
```

...because its still going to a single partition and getting a slice of results from an ordered list

However what if I wanted to something like this:

```
SELECT temperature FROM temperature WHERE event_time > ’2013-04-03 07:01:00′ AND event_time < ’2013-04-03 07:04:00′;
```

If my understanding serves me right, wouldn't this be inefficient since it would need to iterate over every partition?  Not only that but it would then need to be resorted to get it back in time order.

What's the best design to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your query:

```
SELECT temperature FROM temperature WHERE event_time > ’2013-04-03 07:01:00′ AND event_time < ’2013-04-03 07:04:00′;
```

will fail to run. Cassandra really **must** know in which partition has to look for the data you're requesting, that is you always **must** specify the partition key.

In order to efficiently retrieve data for this query you need to model your data around that query too:

```
CREATE TABLE temperature_by_time (
    granularity timestamp,
    event_time timestamp,
    weatherstation_id text,
    temperature text,
    PRIMARY KEY (granularity, event_time)    
);
```

Here I added the field `granularity`. This field allows you to control how wide your partitions will get. A good rule of thumb is to have at most around 10k-100k rows in each partition. Depending on how fast you write to this table you can proceed in different ways. Examples:

---

### Case 1

- You have 10 sensors
- Each sensor gives 1 measure every second

In this case you're going to write 10 measures/second, 36k measures/hour. A good granularity value is then something like `yyyy-mm-dd HH:00:00`, that is you partition your data on hour-by-hour basis:

```
INSERT INTO temperature_by_time (granularity, event_time, ..) VALUES ('2017-01-11 10:00:00', '2017-01-11 10:05:01', ...);
INSERT INTO temperature_by_time (granularity, event_time, ..) VALUES ('2017-01-11 10:00:00', '2017-01-11 10:19:15', ...);
INSERT INTO temperature_by_time (granularity, event_time, ..) VALUES ('2017-01-11 10:00:00', '2017-01-11 10:39:35', ...);
INSERT INTO temperature_by_time (granularity, event_time, ..) VALUES ('2017-01-11 10:00:00', '2017-01-11 10:59:49', ...);

SELECT * FROM temperature_by_time WHERE granularity='2017-01-11 10:00:00';
SELECT * FROM temperature_by_time WHERE granularity='2017-01-11 10:00:00' AND event_time >= '2017-01-1 10:30:00' AND event_time < '2017-01-1 11:00:00';
```

that is you "truncate" the `event_time` to the integer hour, and can get records on hour-per-hour only.

---

### Case 2

- You have 100 sensors
- Each sensor gives 1 measure every second

In this case you're going to write 100 measures/second, 360k measures/hour. Good granularity values are then something like `yyyy-mm-dd HH:00:00`, `yyyy-mm-dd HH:15:00`, `yyyy-mm-dd HH:30:00`, `yyyy-mm-dd HH:45:00`, that is you partition your data on quarters of an hour basis:

```
INSERT INTO temperature_by_time (granularity, event_time, ..) VALUES ('2017-01-11 10:00:00', '2017-01-11 10:05:01', ...);
INSERT INTO temperature_by_time (granularity, event_time, ..) VALUES ('2017-01-11 10:15:00', '2017-01-11 10:19:15', ...);
INSERT INTO temperature_by_time (granularity, event_time, ..) VALUES ('2017-01-11 10:30:00', '2017-01-11 10:39:35', ...);
INSERT INTO temperature_by_time (granularity, event_time, ..) VALUES ('2017-01-11 10:45:00', '2017-01-11 10:59:49', ...);

SELECT * FROM temperature_by_time WHERE granularity='2017-01-11 10:00:00';
SELECT * FROM temperature_by_time WHERE granularity='2017-01-11 10:00:00' AND event_time >= '2017-01-1 10:30:00' AND event_time < '2017-01-1 10:33:00';
```

that is you "truncate" the `event_time` to the quarter of the hour, and can get records on quarters of an hour only.

---

### Case 3

You already know how to proceed...

Comment: So if I wanted to support all of the following types of queries:   
   
1) I want all temps   
2) I want all temps between some time range   
3) I want all temps by weatherstation_id=123   
4) I want all temps by weatherstation_id=123 OR weatherstation_id=456   
5) I want all temps by weatherstation_id=123 over some time range   
6) I want all temps by weatherstation_id=123 OR weatherstation_id=456 over some time range   
   
Would it be fair to say that I would either need multiple tables?  ...or materialized views

Comment: 1. is discouraged, 2. use my table, 3. 4. 5. 6. use your table. You wrote what rules your query: I want temp **by xxx**. Satisfy each **by** with a table.

Comment: Thanks xmas, marked your answer.  But did have hopefully a simple follow on question.  If my granularity is say 1 hour, and I want to search for a months worth of data, on that select's where clause would you specify all the partitions inside a 'WHERE granularity IN(...)'? Cause this list could get mightly long, in my example a month would be over 700 partitions.  Or do people typically just iterate over each partition with separate selects?

Comment: Right answer is option 3: usually people run multiple selects, one for each partition, **in parallel**...

Answer (score 2):

`PRIMARY KEY ((day_of_year), event_time, weatherstation_id)` would give you ability to do ranges of times within a day. If period spans multiple days you make a query per `day_of_year` and merge them in application.

> then need to be resorted to get it back in time order

No it wouldn't in your example because it would return rows ordered by time, one partition at a time. But with the primary key I listed above it would list them by time independent of weatherstation_id.