# Sliding Window TTL in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I'm looking into Cassandra for a potential upcoming project which I think it could be a good fit for. The one potential place where it is stumping me is around a requirement for data retention. Basically we have a schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Things (
  user_id int
  thing_id int
  a text static
  b text static
  .... more static fields
  updated_at timestamp static


  type text
  subthing_id int

  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, thing_id, subthing_id)
)
```

In relational database terms I would say that a Thing belongs to a User and a Thing has many Subthings.

A Thing has various sub-things associated with it that come in at later times that will do a new insert in turn updating the appropriate static fields. We need to store each Thing for 30 days after the last time a subthing was inserted for that Thing. So for example, Thing A and Thing B get inserted. A subthing for Thing B is inserted a week later. Thing A is deleted 30 days after initial insertion. Thing B (and all associated subthings) are deleted 7 days later.

As far as I can tell, I can't just insert with a TTL since I need to update the TTL of the other Thing rows sharing the same user_id and thing_id. I'm also not entirely sure how I would just run a DELETE command here since I'm not deleting by any of the keys. I believe the primary key is correct here since ALL queries will be based on the user_id (except the deletion which is determined by the updated_at).

My other concern is the idea of the tombstones. I have only read about them but the concern here is that I would be deleting potentially millions of these Things each day. Is that going to require daily compaction after the daily deletes are performed?

**Update:**
An alternative I have thought of since the original posting was having a second table that gets inserted to each time a subthing is added. It would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE  Expirations (
  expiry date
  user_id int
  thing_id int
  PRIMARY KEY (expiry, user_id, thing_id)
)
```

Where expiry is the date of the given user_id and thing_id to be deleted. This table would have to be updated as necessary as things are inserted into the Things table and then I would have to run something each day to query for values where expiry is today and iterate over them to delete things from the Things table. I am not sure if this is considered the "Cassandra way" but it seems like it could work.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting challenge. I would use a [map data type](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useMap.html?hl=map) to map each `thing_id` to all its `subthing_id`s. I'd go for something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Things (
  partition_date timestamp,
  insertion_date timestamp,
  user_id int,
  thing_map map<int,int>
  a text static
  b text static
  .... more static fields
  updated_at timestamp static


  type text

  PRIMARY KEY (partition_date, insertion_date, user_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (insertion_date DESC)
```

Here I inserted a new field `insertion_date` that should hold exactly  the insertion date, and a new field `partition_date` that becomes new new only PARTITION KEY, that should store a truncation of the `insertion_date` field, just to avoid some hotspots (I'm assuming that can simply query based on a day field due to your TTL requirements, if you need to query on the `user_id` field things are a bit different). I recently answered to similar questions about this modeling problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41586865/6570821) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39771551/6570821), so have a look at these to get more information about the used technique (it's called *bucketing*).

Then there's the `thing_map` that is the core of your problem. Pushing a new object in the map should reset the TTL for that map entirely, so that could give you exactly the desired behavior. Note that the TTL will remove the *field only*, not the entire row, you'll simply need to test if it's null or not.

Finally, the tombstone behavior is a problem you're gonna having to face. If you can afford a complete row rewrite, that instead of updating only the `map` field you upsert all the row at once you'd get a delete at partition level, and the "reverse time-series" I've modeled with the clustering key should take care of that without too much problems.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have a few questions about it though. So I am pretty sure user_id will have to be the partition key if every query will be based off the user id. The date can be included as part of those queries but is optional. The only time the date would be used and the user_id is not used is in the query to delete expired things. I guess what it comes down to is it better to have the DELETE commands or SELECT queries  hit as few partitions as possible. I am updating the original question with an alternative I thought might work as well... Let me know your thoughts on that.

Comment: @ShaneAndrade: You can always put the `date` together with the `user_id` to better partition your data. As already said, you can find how to do this in the links I posted. Also note that if you use `TTL` then data will disappear *automagically*, so you don't need to perform any `SELECT/DELETE` at all. Having two tables is another viable alternative, but you have `TTL`...